# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 11200]

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, python-3.x

I am receiving the following error. I can't seem to figure out the exact change I need to make to my code to get solve this problem. I feel like it should be straightforward but I'm banging my head against the computer.

**Here is the error message:**
*ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 11200]*

**Here is my code:**

````
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

train_data = pd.read_csv("training/all.lst",sep=' ')
y_train = train_data["status"]
train_data.drop(labels="status", axis=1, inplace=True)

X_train = train_data.values[0:10000]
X_test = train_data.values[10000:]

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

state = 12  
test_size = 0.30  
  
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=test_size, random_state=state)

lr_list = [0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]

for learning_rate in lr_list:
    gb_clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=20, learning_rate=learning_rate, max_features=2, max_depth=2, random_state=0)
    gb_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Learning rate: ", learning_rate)
    print("Accuracy score (training): {0:.3f}".format(gb_clf.score(X_train, y_train)))
    print("Accuracy score (validation): {0:.3f}".format(gb_clf.score(X_val, y_val)))
```
````

Comment: You've split X into X_train and X_test, but haven't done the same for y.

Comment: Perfect! That was it! Thank you!